# contact sensor has no member named contacts

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was following [this](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=contact_sensor&cat=sensors) tutorial , but as i try to build the code i get theis error msg:

```
/usr/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/socket_ops.ipp:266:5: note:   ‘boost::asio::detail::socket_ops::bind’
 int bind(socket_type s, const socket_addr_type* addr,
     ^
/home/rob/Documents/gazebo_contact_tutorial/ContactPlugin.cc: In member function ‘virtual void gazebo::ContactPlugin::OnUpdate()’:
/home/rob/Documents/gazebo_contact_tutorial/ContactPlugin.cc:43:34: error: ‘class gazebo::sensors::ContactSensor’ has no member named ‘Contacts’
   contacts = this->parentSensor->Contacts();
```

How to remove it? I am using ros indigo.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242622/contact-sensor-has-no-member-named-contacts/) by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 932 on 2016-08-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ans: [enter](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/14278/contact-sensor-has-no-member-named-contacts/)

---

Originally posted by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) with karma: 932 on 2016-08-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-08-30**:
I really appreciate you reporting back on the answer to this question, but cross-posting to `answers.gazebosim.org` is really bad style, especially if your only motivation is "to get answer quickly." (as you wrote in [error launching world file in gazebo](http://answers.ros.org/question/242180).